# webRequest permission malformed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set up permission for Chrome so it can ask for webRequest.

However, if I add the permission like in the manual here http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "*://*.google.com"
  ],
  ...
}
```

All I get from Chrome is

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension: Permission
>   '*://*.google.com' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

Where is the error in the manual, what should I do differently?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google is missing slash after the address. This works.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "*://*.google.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

I... am not sure where to report the bug to google exactly.

Comment: There's a big Feedback button in the bottom-right corner of the documentation page. Have you already tried clicking it? ;)

Comment: Yes. :) I am not sure how much is it meant as "general feedback for people unhappy with something" and how much as a genuine bug reporting tool.

Comment: If in doubt, you can always file a report at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list.